# Scala traits and implicit conversion confusion

Tags: scala, traits, implicit-conversion

The following lines work when I enter them by hand on the Scala REPL (2.7.7):

```
trait myTrait {
  override def toString = "something"
}
implicit def myTraitToString(input: myTrait): String = input.toString
object myObject extends myTrait
val s: String = myObject
```

However, if I try to compile file with it I get the following error:

```
[error] myTrait.scala:37: expected start of definition
[error] implicit def myTraitToString(input: myTrait): String = input.toString
[error]          ^
```

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: as i noticed in REPL definitions are implicitly put inside a class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functions can't be defined at the top level.  Put `myTraitToString` in a (companion, if you like) object:

```
object myTrait {
    implicit def myTraitToString(input : myTrait) : String = input.ToString
}
```

And then bring it into scope:

```
import myTrait._
```

Whenever myTraitToString is in scope -- i.e. when you could call it without any dots -- it will be applied implicitly.